# how to use ECHO to print out the du of a home directory in mb?

Tags: disk-usage, echo

This should be a simple hw problem but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. This is an old lab that I missed a while ago (make ups are not allowed), so no I'm not just trying to get other people to do my work I legitimately want to know how to make this work.

> When logging in, you want to see how much data your $HOME directory is using (in term of MB). The command you want to use is du. However du will show you information for entire file/directory hierarchy under $HOME. Use the man page to figure out the options that give you only the size in MB of your $HOME directory. You must print out a useful message before running du. (echo "The size of the home directory is:")

Getting each command to work separately is easy, but I have no idea how to combine them.

Comment: What commands have you tried?  What was the output of those commands?

Comment: At least give us an idea that you homed in on the options for `du` that are relevant based on your analysis of the man page output. **Edit your post** and include these details.

Comment: You can use the method in the answer below, but I expect the question just wanted you to run `echo` and `du` in sequence

Answer (score 1):

you my need this:

```
 echo "$(du -sm $HOME)"
```

or

```
echo "$(du -sm $HOME)mb"
```

Comment: By way of explanation: `-h` means human-friendly values (mb), `-s` means 'summary' (so, doesn't list each file, just the total), and `-m` sets block size to 1M. $HOME resolves to the home dir of the user that is running the shell.

Comment: I think they also want `-S`.